# Unsupported get request. Object with ID '{UserFBID}_{PostID}' does not exist

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I got a FB api issue. I can not get comments of my friend post even I have the post id.
This is my code
`FB.api(__postID + '/comments?access_token=' + access_token + '&fields=id,attachment,created_time,from,message&limit=100', function(response) { console.log(response); })`
This is error when I try to call FB API

> code
>   :
>   100
>   fbtrace_id
>   :
>   "DXSeTkV+R3z"
>   message
>   :
>   "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1743926739162937_1954565944765681' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"
>   type
>   :
>   "GraphMethodException"

ariable __postID is which FB returns when I call `FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', data, function(fbResponse) {})`
My website already have "publish_actions" permission which was approved by Facebook

Thanks

Comment: You need `user_posts` permission to be able to read the post.